# Keeping ASP.NET Session alive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session

With our current setup there is a requirement to maintain mirrored sessions between two sites, one existing ASP.NET website hosted in IIS 6.0 which is now containing the new website in an iFrame, and hosted seperately in IIS 7.5 (It's MVC3).

Does anyone have any suggestions as how to keep the parent session in line with the child website session?

My initial thought was to create an ActionFilter to fire a HttpWebRequest to an HTTPHandler of sorts on the parent site on the OnActionExecuting method. There has been doubts raised as to how this would keep the specific sessions inline, perhaps missing knowledge about session ID's of sorts?

Something like:

```
public override void  OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(
                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HeartbeatURI"]);
        using (var webResponse = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var response = webResponse as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
```

Does anyone have any recommendations/ advice here? Thanks!

**Update:**

After some helpful suggestions I will be investigating whether a solution from the browser, something like:

```
function setHeartbeat() {
    setTimeout("heartbeat()", 300000); // every 5 min
}

function heartbeat() {
    $.get(
        "http://soemthing:1234/heartbeathandler.ashx",
        null,
        function(data) {
            setHeartbeat();
        },
        "json"
    );
}
```

Will perform as I require.

Comment: I can't even imagine how you think that code will do what you think it will.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Anything more constructive to add?

Comment: I'm really at a complete loss as to how to address this, as you don't seem to understand how sessions work, from that code. My point is: *That won't work*. But no... I don't have time to explain session basics at this moment. Maybe later I'll take a stab at an answer.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Very much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27090/Sharing-Session-Across-Applications

Comment: @daryal Thanks for the link, as far as I am aware, the requirement is not to share session data, but to simply maintain the active state of the parent session whilst the child is active. We have little access to the code-base of the parent site, thus the suggestion of a pseudo-heartbeat style implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental issues your code example is not taking into consideration:

First, sessions are per-client. This solution attempts to 'heartbeat' a single connection from the *secondary server*. So it won't work.

Second, sessions require client interaction, either via cookies or special, extra URL values. This solution makes no attempt to incorporate those, so no session will be created at all.

EDIT: There's also a third problem: In-process sessions are not guaranteed to stay alive *no matter what you do*; the application is subject to being recycled at any time, and application recycles will wipe in-process session values. So, you would need to have some external session management system, so that sessions (on *both* servers) are maintained.

---

Really, though; it's pretty brittle to try to keep sessions maintained like this. It sounds like it's really important to your application, but there's almost no guarantee it will work all the time. Rearcitecting your application not to require sessions, or to be able to rebuild them on the fly, would be a better option, IMO.

Comment: The first point is primarily why I am posting the question to SO. Clearly the code example doesn't take this into account so I am looking for a solution that does... Regarding your second point, the requirement is simply to hit an HTTP handler that the client dev team has written at a specified URL. Are you suggesting this approach will not work regardless?

Comment: Yes, that approach will not work regardless; no session will be maintained/refreshed because you are making no attempt to pass in the session-relevant information, which is most likely contained in cookie values. Making a 'refresh' of a page from the *web browser* works because the web browser sends the session cookies with every request. Your solution does not do that.

Comment: So, as a solution, sending a 'refresh' from the client to the handler would also pass in the session cookie information? I assume this could be handled via javascript? As an alternative, do I not have access to the Session information from the HttpContext.Current? Could this not be made use of?

Comment: Actually, sending it to an ASHX handler *won't* work by default, because by default, ASHX handlers are set not to recognize sessions. You have to apply a certain attribute to the handler to get that to work. Assuming you do that, yes; 'refreshing' some URL from the website within the browser will serve to keep the session alive, and you would most likely do that with Javascript. I would suggest using tiny AJAX requests. **But**, there's another big caveat I neglected to mention, that I'm editing into my answer, now.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts; this process is entirely edge-case mitigation regardless of the outcome. It's supposed to maintain a user authentication and nothing else, without this the parent will bounce the user to the login of the site, which whilst not detrimetal does not provide an entirely satisfactory user experience. I will take the AJAX approach via jS/jQuery and investigate this further.